# PHP/MySQL - Random semicolon output

Tags: php

I have this script to output everything from table called Articles.

If I load this script there are random semicolons coming at front of my table like this ; ;

This is my code:

```
    if($_SESSION['rights'] == 2){
    include_once "scripts/mysql123.php";

    //menu
    echo "<a href=\"newarticle.php\">Pridať nový článok</a><br/><br/><br/>";

    //Connect to MySQL Server
    mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

    //Select Database
    mysql_select_db($dbname);

    //display all users
    echo "<table class=\"tableClients\" style=\"text-align: center;\">";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Názov článku</th>
            <th>Vytvorené</th>
            <th>Upraviť</th>
            <th>Vymazať</th>
        \n";
        echo "</tr>\n";
    $qry_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Articles`") or die(mysql_error());
    while($qry = mysql_fetch_array( $qry_result )){
        echo "<tr>\n";
        echo "
            <td>".$qry[id]."</td>
            <td>".$qry[articlename]."</td>
            <td>".date("d.m.Y H:m:i",$qry[created])."</td>
            <td><a href=\"editarticle.php\"><img src=\"img/tools.png\" width=\"30\" /></a></td>;
            <td><a href=\"deletearticle.php\"><img src=\"img/delete.png\" width=\"30\" /></a></td>;
        \n";
        echo "</tr>\n"; 
    }

    echo "</table>\n";


    //Close connection
    mysql_close(mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass));
}
else{
    echo "Musíte mať administrátorské práva.";  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are outputting them yourself as part of the long string literal, at the ends of these lines:

```
<td><a href=\"editarticle.php\"><img src=\"img/tools.png\" width=\"30\" /></a></td>;
<td><a href=\"deletearticle.php\"><img src=\"img/delete.png\" width=\"30\" /></a></td>;
```

Just remove the semicolons there.

Comment: Jesus, I am so blind... Thanks much.